# facebook sdk 3.0 photo tags value and key

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
String tags = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < ischecked.length; i++) {
if (i == 0) {
    sb.append("[");
}
if (ischecked[i]) {
    sb.append("{\"tag_uid\":" + FBFriendlist.get(i).getFBFriendid() + "},");
}
if (i == ischecked.length - 1) {
    sb.replace(sb.length() - 1, sb.length(), "]");
    tags = sb.toString();
}
}
params.putString("tags", tags);

Request requestphoto = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),"me/photos", params,
                            HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

 @Override
 public void onCompleted(Response response) {
     Log.e("id", response.getGraphObject().getProperty("id").toString());
     Intent intent = new Intent(PaintQuitGameScene.this, UserProfileScene.class);
     startActivity(intent);
 finish();
 }
 });

 requestphoto.executeAsync();
```

When execute, it return `nullpointerexception`.

What is the format for tags?

Comment: Where are you getting the NPE? It's likely that the response.getGraphObject() does not have an "id" property, which is why your .toString() call is generating an NPE. Try calling response.getError, and see if there were any errors returned from the service. From the way you're creating your request, I can say with a high degree of confidence that your request is not properly formatted. Try using the graph explorer tool to test your requests first - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: @MingLi When I comment out the `param.putstring`. It return no error, can get the `id` property.

Comment: This is because "tags" is not a valid parameter for a GET request for /me/photos, which is why you're probably getting an error response back from the server.

Comment: @Ming Li, I had added String Array into tags it return no error but not successful tag friend. The String Array was `{1111111,22222222}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying the get pictures that your friends are tagged in, or tag your friends in some pictures? You should read the graph API documentation for possible parameters to the /me/photos request https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Comment: @MingLi First, I upload a photo to facebook, then tag friend into the photo that uploaded. that all

Comment: I don't think there's an API to do that.

Comment: @MingLi Why not? I saw other people can tag friends

Comment: I was wrong, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

See the photo API reference here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags